# Как установить GNUwin32?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

Люди, подскажите пожалуйста, как установить GNUwin32 для zip команд на windows 7. Я хотела сделать программу, которая описывается в книге и там необходимо установить этот пакет. Сделала все как там. Программа не работает. Прилагаю фото[image: Фото из учебника] Я установила вот этот пакет с официального сайта gnu. [image: Пакет с сайта] Установила в переменную path ;C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\bin. Программа не работает. Пишут необходимо прописать вот это:
print (zip_command) . Но эта команда ничего не выводит. Пишет is not defined..Помогите пожалуйста. Вот сам код программы

```
import os
import time

source = ['"C:\\My Documents"', 'C:\\Code']
target_dir = 'D:\Программирование' 

target = target_dir + os.sep + time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S') + '.zip'

zip_command = "zip -qr {0} {1}".format(target, ' '.join(source))

if os.system(zip_command) == 0:
    print('Резервная копия успешно создана в', target)
else:
    print('Создание резервной копии НЕ УДАЛОСЬ')
```

Comment: GnuWin32 нужен для работы с zip? `Пишет is not defined.` вот тут подробнее -- сама ошибка даст подсказку о проблеме, ошибку и нужно добавить в вопрос. А zip есть в `C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\bin`? Попробуйте в консоли запустить `zip`.

Comment: Да есть, там несколько exe файлов. В консоли пишет, что zip не является внутренней или внешней командой

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все, я нашла ошибку. Я вместо C:\Program Files (x86) писала просто C:\Program Files. Теперь все работает